# How to initialize static pointer array of objects of same class with nullptr?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

I'm trying to initialize a pointer array of same class objects. Here's the class:

```
class Correspondent{
    private:
        static Correspondent *correspondent[maxCorrespondents];
}
```

I tried in contsructor. but it got initialized every time.

```
Correspondent::Correspondent(string n,string c) {
    name = n;
    country = c;
    for(int i=0;i<=maxCorrespondents;i++){
        correspondent[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *one* translation unit where this variable is defined:

```
Correspondent* Correspondent::correspondent[maxCorrespondents]{};
```

That's it. This aggregate initializes the array, which in turn default initializes each pointer. And since pointers are fundamental types, that will do zero initialization, setting them all to `nullptr`.

Answer (score 1):

Objects with static storage duration are always zero-initialized. So `correspondent` array will be filled with zeros without writing any additional code. From **[dcl.init].10**

> Every object of static storage duration is zero-initialized at program startup before any other initialization takes place.

Also it might be a good idea to use `::std::array` wrapper and to introduce a type alias to avoid duplication in array declaration and definition:

```
class Correspondent
{
    private: using Correspondents = ::std::array<Correspondent *, maxCorrespondents>;
    private: static Correspondents correspondents;
};

Correspondent::Correspondents Correspondent::correspondents;
```